# back up DB to an older version

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have two SQL Servers of different versions: 2014 and 2012. I cannot upgrade the oldest to the newest one. Can I back up a DB on 2014 so that I can restore it on 2012? I would like to restore both schema and data. I would also prefer to do it through backing up, not through scripting out. Right now I am getting an error saying something like "the versions are incompatible, and you cannot restore the DB". I appreciate your help.

Comment: You cannot restore a database from an newer version of SQL,Server to an old one; SQL Server is not forward compatible. If you need to data, objects, etc from a newer version of SQL Server you will need to script out everything you for the objects; then you have either script out the data or use an ETL process to load it to the older version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't back up & restore the database from a higher (2014) to lower (2012) version.

You can generate a script from SQL Server 2014 (DB creation and data creation script) and you can run on SQL server 2012. Only scripting is an option in this scenario to create a database/restore a database from SQL server 2014 to 2012.

You can certainly take a back from SQL server 2012 and restore in the SQL server 2014.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. Is it the only answer?

Comment: @Romano The short answer is that you **cannot** use backup/restore. This is a frequent question and you can easily find suggestions by searching. There are likely tools you can **purchase** that do this - and SSIS as suggested by Larnu can. Beware that success depends on not using features that are not available in the older version.